# Salesforce Backup and Restore Managed Package - Failure upon initial PostgreSQL Schema creation (1st Backup)

Tags: backup

I realize this is a new product and is really more beta level then anything. But one of my clients org just got a license for the Salesforce Backup And Restore (Managed Package). Documentation is very thin on this but from my understanding, data is ultimately backed up in an AWS S3 bucket. I can't seem to be able to successfully create the first backup.
Instructions were followed from [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.backup_restore_install.htm&type=5) / 1 object selected for backup.

When activating the backup policy / (there appears to be no way to schedule these currently) it seems to run at 4pm and fail immediately after 10 seconds of processing. The error log displayed is too vague on the Log Record.

> Message = Backup policy execution completed with one or more errors.
>
> Elapsed time: 9 seconds

The error in the browser console while viewing
the log records is.

> errorList=StatementCallback; uncategorized
> SQLException for SQL [CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS
> hive.x00d1i000001dlpouae]; SQL state [null]; error code [16777216];
> Query failed (#20220305_220051_00002_nay8z): metastore:9083:
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20220305_220051_00002_nay8z):
> metastore:9083: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Anyone run into this?

Comment: I think you need to contact Support. I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.. much respect for you over the years..  A ticket has been logged. I was trying to go through multiple angles as well.  Appreciate the response!

Comment: Just an update.. This particular issue seems to have been solved by SFDC per the below response in the Case (I asked for more detail but was unable to obtain it) "“There were a number of fixes that we implemented, including pushing updates to the backend and re-establishing the connection to the metastore.
For the restore issue, that is something that our product team is currently working on.”   I have run into numerous other issues however for which additional tickets are open.